# Cloud Foundry - node.js - MySQL

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, node-mysql

Please help me on how to connect/bind to mysql services of cloud foundry using node.js and node-mysql module?

In cloud foundry we can connect/bind to mysql services and cloud foundry supports applications of type spring, node.js, etc,...

I have successfully develpoed a spring application and hosted in cloudfoundry and able to connect/bind to mysql services of cloudfoundry. Also I could able to connect to mysql running locally using node-mysql module.

But I want to connect/bind to mysql services of cloud foundry using node.js and node-mysql module and there are no examples related to the same. Is it possible to do this?

Any help in this regard is greatly appriciated.

Thank you.
Regards,
Kishan.G

Answer (score 2):

I think the first thing to note is that CloudFoundry will very shortly support the automatic reconfiguration of Node.JS applications much in the same vain as we currently do with Rails. This means being able to develop a Node.JS app locally that uses MySQL and when deploying it to CloudFoundry it will automatically be reconfigured to use a bound service instead.

Until that feature is live, which as I said won't be long, you will have to use the VCAP environment variables to configure the connection at runtime. There is a pretty good example of this approach being used with Node.JS here - http://www.mihswat.com/2011/05/04/getting-started-with-cloud-foundry-using-a-node-js-and-mongodb-application/ albeit for MongoDB, the approach is exactly the same.

The part to pay particular attention to is where the author reads the environment in to a hash with the following code;

```
var boundServices = process.env.VCAP_SERVICES 
  ? JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) : null;
```

and then uses them to initialise a connection;

```
if (boundServices == null) {
  db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/analytics');
} else {
  credentials = boundServices['mongodb-1.8'][0]['credentials'];
  db = mongoose.createConnection("mongo://"
                         + credentials["username"]
                         + ":" + credentials["password"]
                         + "@" + credentials["hostname"]
                         + ":" + credentials["port"]
                         + "/" + credentials["db"]);
}
```

If you need any further pointers, then let me know.